# Is there a proper way to dynamically update parts of transforms and transitions programmatically? e.g. transform-origin or duration

Tags: css, webkit, css-transitions

I am building an iOS Safari touch-based app and find CSS transitions and transforms work great.

But I have two things I can't seem to achieve using just JavaScript and CSS.

1. Usually I want the element to translate with a duration of 0.2s.  But in code I occasionally want to instantly translate (initial positioning).  If I update the duration to 0 or remove the transition style entirely, it doesn't seem to have an effect (acts as if the 0.2s is immutable)
2. When zooming I want to update the transform-origin property.  This also does not seem to work, and seems stuck at my original stylesheet-set value.  Specifically I am trying to do this on the gesturestart and gestureend events

Hopefully there is an approach to making this work.  Maybe setTimeout async processing?

### Update:

I have a js fiddle example to better illustrate my problem in #1, and it turns out that setTimeout fixes it, but it's a strange solution that I'd be interested in improving:

http://jsfiddle.net/w9E7t/

It seems like I'm unable to do these steps synchronously:

1. set appropriate classes for an instant transition
2. apply transition style
3. reset classes to their default (with transition) state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can accomplish this by using two CSS classes, one which sets the `timing-duration` to 0s and the other which sets it to 200ms and then applying the classes programmatically in JS. Take a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KgLMX/1/) for an example.

   One of Web development's best practices is to separate your document's parts into structure/content (HTML), presentation (CSS), and interaction/behavior (JS). In the example above, the presentation of the content (a timed translation) stays defined in CSS while JS is used only to respond to an interaction (a MouseClick event).
2. You should be able to change an element's `transform-origin` using the `WebkitTransformOrigin` style property in JS. Here is an example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZaKC7/).  I tested this on my iPhone4 and it correctly logged the new transform-origins in the console. Again, this can also be achieved by using JS only to listen for the gesture events and updating the element's class, while keeping the style rules of the class defined in your presentation logic (CSS).

Note well: In my examples, I am updating the element's .className. Since it is possible that your elements already have many classes, you may need to implement addClass/removeClass functions to properly set the correct classes, several examples of which can found on the Web.

### Update:

Sorry for the delay... There are two ways you can approach this problem and the first you have already discovered.

Another way to handle switching back the class name is to use the `webkitTransitionEnd` property. This fires whenever a transition on the element finishes. It would look like this:

```
document.getElementById('puck').addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', function() {
    puck
        .removeClass('without_transition')
        .addClass('with_transition')
}, false);
```

Unfortunately, when the `transition-duration` property is set to 0, this event is not fired :( I'm not sure if that is by design or a bug, but that's just how it's currently implemented (though I'm guessing it's by design since at this point the browser is not *really* doing a transition but rather just applying the transformation). The workaround in this approach is to set the `transition-duration` to 1ms (which will essentially look instant).

While the setTimeout approach looks hackish, many mobile framework groups use it throughout their code since the function will fire *after* the transition that occurs from switching classes (similar to transitionEnd). Take a look at Sencha Touch and you will find it numerous times.

I've forked your JSfiddle to show my example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/csVnd/).

Comment: Thanks for your anwser!  It looks like in most cases you can simply update this property as long as there is a real physical delay involved. I updated my question with a jsfiddle example showing the exact issue I see, and it looks like I need to introduce a delay with setTimeout.  I want to reset back to the "with_transition" class as in most cases, that is the default.  Curious your thoughts

Comment: Thanks for the update, this is going to be helpful in yet a  _different_ case! :)

Is it just me or are all the introductory transition examples on the web which have a link :hover effect pretty much useless?  haha